# Test if one array is a subset of another

Tags: php, arrays, set

How can I determine if one array is a subset of another (all elements in the first are present in the second)?

```
 $s1 = "string1>string2>string3>string4>string5>string6>";
 $arr1 = explode(">", $s1);
 $s2 = "string1>string4>string5";
 $arr2 = explode(">", $s2);

 $isSubset = /* ??? */
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you start from strings, you could check `strstr($fullString,$subsetStr);`. But that'll only work when all chars have the same order: `'abcd','cd'` will work, but `'abcd','ad'` won't.

But instead of writing your own, custom, function you should know that PHP has *TONS* of array functions, so its neigh on impossible that there isn't a std function that can do what you need it to do. In this case, I'd suggest `array_diff`:

```
$srcString = explode('>','string1>string2>string3>string4>string5');
$subset = explode('>','string3>string2>string5');
$isSubset = array_diff($subset,$srcString);
//if (empty($isSubset)) --> cf comments: somewhat safer branch:
if (!$isSubset)
{
    echo 'Subset';
    return true;
}
else
{
    echo 'Nope, substrings: '.implode(', ',$isSubset).' Didn\'t match';
    return false;
}
```

Comment: No, I do mean empty: in the example given the subset string is an actual subset, but array_diff does return an empty array. Why check falsy? please explain... I know `isset` and `== null` can cause issues, but I've had no issues with `empty` so far

Comment: Please see [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/) for why not.

Comment: Thanks, but as it says: there's no real difference here: `empty` === loose comparison to `false`, so `empty($var)` and `!$var` are interchangeable. The only benefit AFAIK, is that `!$var` throws errors when `$var` is undefined. This isn't possible in the snippet above. I'll edit my answer, though, just in case someone, for whatever reason, decides to add numerous lines of code between the `array_diff` and `if()`

Comment: Well, exactly. You should use `empty` only for variables which *may legitimately not exist*. Otherwise you're unnecessarily foregoing the advantages of PHP's error reporting. It's just a rule of thumb you should follow to make your own life easier by not suppressing error reporting.

Comment: I don't mind being down-voted, but I do mind that people don't bother to explain _why_

Comment: As one who liberally changes `empty($x)` to `!$x` when I find it, this is one case where `empty($x)` really is more expressive. "Is the array empty?" AFAIK there is no downside to using `empty` here.

Comment: $isSubset should be named $isntSubset, no?

Answer (score 77):

```
if (array_intersect($array1, $array2) == $array1) {
    // $array1 is a subset of $array2
}
```

Comment: array_intersect :) , nice solution

Comment: Yours is actually better though. :)

Comment: @Tamas Well, no, `array_diff` is actually a lot more elegant. :)

Comment: array_diff(['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b']) will return ['c']. However array_diff(['c'], ['d']) will also return ['c'] so it's not as elegant a solution actually.

Comment: @aleemb Well... if `array_diff` results in anything but an empty array, the array is ***not*** a subset of the other. If the result is an empty array it's a subset. So, the results in your example are expected and correct and exactly what we want.

Comment: Much more intuitive answer. Thanks!

Comment: A wholesome comment section :)

Comment: this doesnt work when testing with multidimensional arrays! returns true for arrays that have different values on level 2 or deeper

Answer (score 31):

Simple: use array subtraction.

On array subtraction, you will know whether or not one array is a subset of the other.

Example:

```
if (!array_diff($array1, $array2)) {
    // $array1 is a subset of $array2
}
```

Reference: [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

You can use `array_intersect` also.

Try that

Comment: array_diff(['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b']) will return ['c']. However array_diff(['c'], ['d']) will also return ['c'] so it's not as elegant a solution actually.

Comment: `array_diff_assoc` is safer when comparing multi-dimensional arrays if you have specific types for each key in the array

Comment: @aleemb I don't see your point. For this solution:

`array_diff(['a', 'b','c'], ['a', 'b'])` returns `['c']`, which means array1 is not subset of array2 --> correct.

`array_diff(['c'], ['d'])` returns `['c']`, which means array1 is not subset of array2 --> correct.

What is wrong?

Comment: I think a problem is that this solution is hard to think about. _array_intersect_ solution has no negation and does not involve mathematics. It's easy to mentally visualize.

Comment: But array_diff converts both to string, so if you have two arrays of objects, you'll get the error "object of class _____ could not be converted to string"

Answer (score 1):

I would create an associated array of the larger array, then iterate through the smaller array, looking for a non collision, if you find one, return false.

```
function isSubset($arr1,$arr2){
    $map = Array();
    for ($i=0;$i<count($arr1);$i++){
      $map[$arr[$i]]=true;
    }
    for ($i=0;$i<count($arr2);$i++){
       if (!isset($map[$arr2[$i]])){
          return false;
       }
    }
    return true;
```

Comment: That's the most complicated `array_flip` I've ever seen.

Comment: It's actually the most simple way you could do an array_flip.  It is almost certainly what happens behind the scenes of array_flip.  But thanks for telling me about that function.  Good to know.

Answer (score 1):

```
$s1 = "1>2>3>4>5>6>7";

$arr1 = explode(">",$s1);

$s2 = "1>2>3";

$arr2 = explode(">",$s2); 

if(isSub($arr1,$arr2)){

         echo 'true';

}else{

         echo 'false';
}

function isSub($a1,$a2){

    $num2 = count($a2);
    $sub  = $num2;

    for($i = 0;$i < $num2 ;$i++){
        if(in_array($a2[$i],$a1)){
            $sub--;
        }
    }
    return ($sub==0)? true:false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple function which will return true if array is exact subset otherwise false. Solution is applicable for two dimensional array as well.

```
 function is_array_subset($superArr, $subArr) {
        foreach ($subArr as $key => $value) {
            //check if keys not set in super array OR values are unequal in both array.
            if (!isset($superArr[$key]) || $superArr[$key] != $value) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```