# PHP Array in Array with Multidimensional Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I got two arrays and want to check if the second array is in the first. The arrays:

**First Array:**

```
array(1) {
  ["group"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["create"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["edit"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["delete"]=>
    bool(true)
  }
}
```

**Second Array**

```
array(1) {
  ["group"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["create"]=>
    bool(true)
  }
}
```

**The depth can be different**

`in_array` doesn't work -> array to conversion error and it doesn't mind the assoc allocation
I tried to search and tested a lot but doesn't found what I need. I Hope someone of you can help me!

Comment: Try checking this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128323/in-array-and-multidimensional-array

Comment: @Sasikumar that doesn't work, I already tried this and it also doesn't fit my goal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to check one array is exact subset of another array - php array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12276565/how-to-check-one-array-is-exact-subset-of-another-array-php-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the approach from @Jignesh Prajapati I found finally a solution. Thank you!

```
function test( $first_array, $second_array ) {
    $found = FALSE;

    if( is_bool( $second_array ) && is_bool( $first_array ) ) {
        return $second_array === $first_array;
    }

    if( is_array( $first_array ) && is_array( $second_array ) ) {
        foreach( $second_array as $key => $value ) {
            foreach( $first_array as $key_1 => $value_1 ) {
                if( $key === $key_1 ) {
                    $found = test( $value_1, $value );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $found;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$cnt = 0;
    foreach ($second_array as $key => $value) {
            foreach ($first_array as $key_1 => $value_1) {
                if($key == $key_1){
                    $cnt++;
                }
            }
    }

    if($cnt > 0){
        echo "second array element in first array";
    }else{
        echo "not in array";
    }
```

Comment: I see what you tried, a good approach, but it doesn't fit if the second array is `[ 'group' => [ 'list' => FALSE ] ]`

Comment: $cnt = 0;
 if(count($second_array) > 0){
  foreach ($second_array as $key => $value) {
   if(count($first_array) > 0){
    foreach ($first_array as $key_1 => $value_1) {
     if($key == $key_1){
      $cnt++;
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }